# MobileFirst Server not startng untill JVM.options is edited in Windows 8.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

1. I have faced a problem like Mobilefirst server not starting until i
   edit the **JVM.options** `(-DOS.name = Windows 8)` in the eclipse.
2. I need to do the above step manually whenever i create a new workspace
3. Is there
       any other way to completely resolve this problem.

> Note : I am using Windows 8.1

**Error Log**

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 10777
CWWKE0005E: The runtime environment could not be launched.
CWWKE0018E: An exception occurred while launching the runtime environment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebSphere-DefaultExtension-windowsnt(unknown)
com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.LaunchException: Caught unexpected exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebSphere-DefaultExtension-windowsnt(unknown)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.KernelBootstrap.rethrowException(KernelBootstrap.java:418)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.KernelBootstrap.go(KernelBootstrap.java:183)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.Launcher.createPlatform(Launcher.java:131)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:55)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.cmdline.EnvCheck.main(EnvCheck.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebSphere-DefaultExtension-windowsnt(unknown)
    at java.util.jar.Attributes$Name.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.BootstrapManifest.getOSExtensionDefinition(BootstrapManifest.java:157)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.KernelBootstrap.go(KernelBootstrap.java:123)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: not starting... with which error in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding that option to the eclipse.ini file located in your Eclipse installation folder, instead of in the JVM.options of your workspace.

Comment: Make sure you're using Eclipse Java EE. Make sure you're using Java 7.